# Nancy: How to log body of response in Nancy

Tags: c#, rest, nancy

In case we search for a failure in our application, we want to add the possibility to log all request and responses given by our Nancy service. In order to accomplish this, we added some pipeline hooks. 
But unfortunately I'm not able to get the body of our responses. When I execute the delegate that renders the contents to the response stream (Contents), my response stream (ms) is disposed.

```
public void LogResponse(NancyContext context) {

    string CreateResponseMessage() {
        return $"Response (Client: {context.Request.UserHostAddress}) [{context.Request.Method}] {context.Request.Url}, " +
        $"Status code: {(int) context.Response.StatusCode} {context.Response.StatusCode}";
    }

    string CreateContentMessage() {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // For some reason, when executing this line, my ms is disposed
            context.Response.Contents(ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms)) {
                var headers = FormatHeaders(context.Response.Headers);
                var content = sr.ReadToEnd();

                return
                    $"Headers:{NewLine}{headers}{NewLine}" +
                    $"Body:{NewLine} {content}";
            }
        }
    }

    Log.Info(CreateResponseMessage());
    Log.Verbose(CreateContentMessage);
}
```

Is this the wrong way to get the content of the body? Is there a way at all?